# MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. so can someone solve to me

Tags: unity-game-engine

help me guys I am getting this error.

the line of code its highlighting is this Player.SetActive(true);

and this is the entire void its in
public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
{

```
    Player.SetActive(true);

    disableDeathScreen();

    curentHealth++;




    addHealth();



    StartCoroutine(Text());
    




    // Load another ad:
    Advertisement.Initialize("");

}
```

it happens when I return to the mainmenu "while in playmode" then go back to the game scene it gives this error

Comment: Well, it's pretty much just what it says.  If that is the actual code that is breaking, then your reference to `Player` is gone.  Meaning you've destroyed it somewhere or didn't assign it.

Answer (score 0):

In a different script, the Player object must have been called via Destroy(). Check your other scripts for references to this object.